# How to check given word occures at last position of string in php

Tags: php, file-extension

I want to get an alternate of an sql query `WHERE field LIKE '%subStr'` in PHP for example

actually I want to conditionally of different file types so I want to check whether the extension is `.ppt` or `.pptx` or `.pptm` `.ppm` or any thing else.

Comment: What code you tried so far?

Comment: I tried striPos but it also returns true or number if substr is between the name i mean if the file name contains .doc in its name where as the actual extension is .txt then it doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way.

```
$file = 'my-file.ppt';
$parts = pathinfo($file);
$extensions = array("ppt", "pptx", "pptm", "ppm");


if (in_array($parts['extension'], $extensions)) {
   echo "we have {$parts['extension']}";
}
else {
   echo "no matches";
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can easily strip out the last characters of a filename string to achieve this:

```
<?php

$filename = "myFile.txt";
$pathinfo = pathinfo($filename);
$extension = $pathinfo['extension'];

switch ($extension) {
    case "ppt":
        echo "Extension is .ppt";
        break;
    case "txt":
        echo "Extension is .txt";
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this was a great solution I dint knew about this function.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of **`array_pop`** and **`explode`**

```
<?php
$filename='new.newfile.ppt';
$file=explode('.',$filename);
echo $ext = array_pop($file); // ppt
```

Comment: Although you could achieve this using end in a single line: `$ext = end(explode('.', $filename));`

Comment: @r3mus, Yeah i know , i wrote it like that so OP can understand with ease.